# Getting "Cannot use dynamic template data with a legacy template" with non-legacy template

Tags: java, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I'm attempting to integrate with Sendgrid and am having a heck of a time.  I have created a dynamic template - a new one, not a legacy one - with a single handle bar (first_name) in it.  It has a subject.  But I'm getting a load of errors that I could use some help with.

First the code:

```
public void sendEmail(String toEmail, String toName) throws IOException {
    String fromEmail = "validated-sendgrid-address@example.com";
    String fromName = "Blah blah";

    SendGrid sendGrid = new SendGrid("the_api_key");
    Request request = new Request();
    try {
        request.setMethod(Method.POST);
        request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
        String body = "see below...";

        request.setBody(body);
        Response response = sendGrid.api(request);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
        System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Taken almost entirely from the Java example code.

The JSON body, pretty printed...

```
{
  "from": {
    "email": "validated-sendgrid-address@example.com",
    "name": "Blah blah"
  },
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "stdunbar@example.com",
          "name": "Blah Blah"
        }
      ],
      "dynamic_template_data": {
        "first_name": "Babaloo"
      }
    }
  ],
  "template_id": "[d-lotsandlotsofcharacters]"
}
```

And then a bunch of errors that make no sense (all of which link to a 404):

1. Cannot use dynamic template data with a legacy template ID - `I'm not using a legacy template id according to the UI`
2. The template_id must be a valid GUID, you provided '[d-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx]' - `I sent what I was given on the UI`.
3. The subject is required. You can get around this requirement if you use a template with a subject defined or if every personalization has a subject defined. - `My template has a subject`
4. Unless a valid template_id is provided, the content parameter is required. There must be at least one defined content block. We typically suggest both text/plain and text/html blocks are included, but only one block is required. - `A valid template_id was provided`

I'm guessing the first issue is the `template_id` field.  It's strange JSON in that the value includes the array open/close.  Putting the value inside as text gives a parse error so Sendgrid must be taking that directly.

**Any** directional help would be most appreciated.  The docs are rather challenging

Comment: In your question,  your template ID is enclosed in square brackets, is that part of you obscuring your ID, or did you submit it to the API with the square brackets? If so, they aren't needed and the template_id should just be `d-xxxxxxxetc`.

Comment: Thanks @philnash - that got me further to a different error that I'll work on.  I got the "array" notation from [here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-transactional-templates) - perhaps I misread but it looks like an array in quotes to me.

Comment: Ah, I think the array in quotes there is just supposed to represent the string that you replace with your actual template_id. Let me know if I can help with the next error you're on to. I'll add this as an answer for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

In your example, you show the `template_id` as `"template_id": "[d-lotsandlotsofcharacters]"`. The square brackets are not required in the `template_id`, it should just be `"template_id": "d-lotsandlotsofcharacters"`.

The [documentation for sending an email with a dynamic template](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-transactional-templates#send-a-transactional-email) does show the the `template_id` example as `"template_id":"[template_id]"` but the entire `[template_id]` string should be substituted for the real ID.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error. I had failed to copy the Template ID correctly. The Template ID is displayed when you click in the sidebar of the SendGrid control panel, "Email API ➔ Dynamic Templates". It is not the same as the ID you get from the `/v3/designs` endpoint, alas.

The error message is ambiguous. It says `"Cannot use dynamic template data with a legacy template ID"`, when in fact it should say `"Template ID not found"`. I was misled into believing that my Template was a legacy version, which it was not. Four hours I'll never get back.